# How to backup and restore the raven database by C# console application coding?

Tags: ravendb

i need to backup and restore raven database by c# console application.i don't want to achieve this by smuggler.it should be a pure c# console application coding.i tried my level best.can you give me a suggestion please?

Comment: What is the problem with Smuggler? It is a console application doing exactly what you want.

Comment: Smuggler.exe can be added as a reference to the project and used just like a class library. You can the write a console application using the smuggler api to do what you are looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Raven.Backup application